# knockout performance issue with updateValue: 'afterkeydown'

Tags: knockout.js

I have a searchbox and a table showing 0 - 100 result rows:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: vm.query,
                              valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown',
                              event: { keypress: vm.keypress} ">

<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: results">
    <tr>
      <td> <p data-bind="text: property1"></p> </td>
      <td> <p data-bind="text: property2"></p> </td>
      ...
```

When I only have 10 rows in the results table, I get ok performance when writing stuff in the input-box. Yellow = javascript is touching the 16 ms limit but not more:
[image: chrome timeline 1]

When I have 100 rows in the results table, performance is horrible when writing stuff in the input-box. Yellow = javascript is through the roof:
[image: chrome timeline 2]

If I remove the `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` there is no performance problems but I have it because when the user presses <kbd>enter</kbd> I'm firing of the search using `event: { keypress: vm.keypress}`.

Is there some performance gotcha with `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` or is this performance problem more likely due to something else in my code?

Comment: Consider to make a fiddle, because I think there are dependencies issues.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the "throttle" extender to asynchronously reevaluate your table.
The details are [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html).

Answer (score 2):

Part of the issue is related to how your `results` is updated. If the changes in `results` are minor, the `foreach` binding is quite fast, but if the values change a lot, it can be quite slow.

My [Repeat plugin](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-repeat) is a good way to gain performance here. Because it repeats the bound element instead of the element's contents, you'll bind to the `tr` instead of the `tbody`:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-bind="repeat: results">
      <td> <p data-bind="text: $item().property1"></p> </td>
      <td> <p data-bind="text: $item().property2"></p> </td>
```